# The server response was: 5.7.7 Sender Unknown in Local Domain

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, email, sendmail

When i tried to send a mail through SMTP server An Exception is coming.
Here is the Exception:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Transaction failed. 
The server response was: 5.7.7 Sender Unknown in Local Domain . at 
System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) at 
System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String 
deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage 
message) at _Default.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
in d:\pjt\mail_check\Default.aspx.cs:line 39
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.nethosted.co.uk/community/unknown-sender-in-local-domain-t2418.html).It may be helpful